# Cannot find aria_s3_copy utility in mariadb 10.5.5

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I am not able to find the Aria utility - aria_s3_copy under bin. I use mariadb official docker image and I do find aria_chk but not aria_s3_copy.

Can you tell me where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aria_s3_copy is in the `mariadb-plugin-s3` package which isn't installed by the [mariadb docker library container image](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/master/10.5/Dockerfile#L98-L100).

Extending the docker container and installing this plugin package is possible.